# 3x3 array with random numbers

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matrix

I need to take the numbers 0-8 and rearrange them randomly in a 3x3 array using a function. What is the simplest way possible?
I need to get [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] as a 3x3 array with the numbers in random order

Comment: Did you make any effort or try anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use a flat list/array with sorted numbers, shuffle them (e.g. using `random.shuffle`), then reshape it into. Python doesn't support arrays natively, so you can use lists instead, then reshape them into lists of list, like:

```
import random

def arrange(x, rows, cols):
    random.shuffle(x)
    return [x[cols * i : cols * (i + 1)] for i in range(rows)]

print(arrange(list(range(9)), 3, 3))
```

[numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) has an [array object](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) that you can use also use, which supports reshaping etc, see the documentation, like:

```
import numpy as np

### Numpy's array solution
def arrange_np(x, rows, cols):
    np.random.shuffle(x)
    return x.reshape(rows, cols)

print(arrange_np(np.arange(9), 3, 3))
```